# Instantiate class dynamically using filename

Tags: ruby

my question is that if i have a class CSVWriter inside a file named csv_writer.rb, then can i instantiate this class using my filename dynamically.

I did tried using Object.const_get() method but it takes the name of the class as string as argument.

So is there anyway to do that in ruby

Thanks

Comment: Or if there is a way to get the classname from the filename provided that there is only one class inside each file.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__FILE__` constant to get the name of the file.

```
# foo.rb
puts __FILE__
```

Output

```
"foo.rb"
```

---

Knowing this, you could do something like

```
# csv_writer.rb

class CsvWriter
  def initialize
    puts "hello"
  end
end

klass = Object.const_get(
          File::basename(__FILE__, ".rb")
            .split("_")
            .map(&:capitalize)
            .join("")
        )

klass.new
```

Output

```
"hello"
```

---

**PS** there's no programmatic way to convert `csv_writer` to `CSVWriter`. How would ruby know to capitalize `csv` to `CSV` (all-caps) but `writer` to only `Writer`?

Comment: but what i want to get is the name of the class inside my file. So suppose if a have a file foo.rb which has a class Foo, how can i get the name of the class( i.e. Foo) bu using the name of my file i.e. foo.rb --- @naomik

Comment: @kunal, ok, I've done *all* of the work for you now.

Comment: Yes i understand and agree to your point. It just was a question that just came into my mind.
Thank You @naomik